# Migrating GNU Mailman server to new hardware

Tags: redhat, rsync, mailman

We have a GNU Mailman server running on some old hardware that is due to be retired soon. I have been trying to figure out where the list/archive data stored so I can just rsync it over to the new server when it comes in but I haven't had much luck. Does anyone know where this data is stored by default? Also, is there anything else I should be concerned about when making a move like this? I don't have much experience with Mailman so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which OS are you running this on, and are you using OS-supplied packages or was it installed manually?

Comment: Old server is running RHEL4 and mailman was installed via the Redhat supplied RPM. The exact package name is mailman-2.1.5.1-34.rhel4.6. The new server would be running RHEL6

Answer (score 2):

The files you want are located in /var/lib/mailman the directories you want to copy are

```
/var/lib/mailman/data
/var/lib/mailman/archives
/var/lib/mailman/lists
```

After you have migrated the server just run

```
check_perms -f
```

To fix the permissions

Comment: I would add a somewhat obvious step of ensuring `mailman` is stopped on both hosts before copying the files. Also _do not_ rebuild the archives. It will change all the public links.

Comment: when I run check_perms -f it finds about 400 issues but says I need to run as root to fix. After elevating to root I run the command again but it won't actually fix the permissions, just  find them. Any ideas?